# Polar velocity given cartesian components

Tags: polar-coordinates

I would like to calculate the polar velocity components given the position $(x,y)$ and velocity $(u_x,u_y)$ in cartesian coordinates. First of all, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta={\rm atan}{(y/x)}$. By now, I know the angle and radius in the global cylindrical coordinate system. I assume that $u=u_re_r+u_\theta e_\theta$. Is it correct to write $u_r=\cos(\theta)u_x + \sin(\theta)u_y$ and $u_\theta=-\sin(\theta)u_x + \cos(\theta)u_y$ ?The problem is that I would like to calculate the components in polar coordinates (not angular velocity though) given that a particle is moving from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$. Thank you in advance for the help given

Comment: Everything looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Remember that

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x'(t) \\ 
y'(t) 
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta (t)) & -r(t) \sin (\theta (t)) \\
 \sin (\theta (t)) & r(t)\cos (\theta (t))
\end{array}
\right)\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 r'(t)\\
\theta '(t)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: $\theta'(t)$  is the angular velocity (rad/s) or the linear velocity (m/s) ?

Comment: The units for $\theta'(t)$ are [rads/s]

Comment: Thus $r(t)\theta'(t)$ is the linear one I assume

Comment: You can do that assuming a referential $\hat{n},\hat{\tau}$. In that referential we have $\dot r\hat{n}+r\dot\theta\hat{\tau}$